# can templates be used in structures definition

Tags: c++, c++11

```
template <class T>
struct node
{
   T data;
   int *p;
};
```

and if yes how do we define objects of such a template also i would like to know do we allocate memory to dynamically created objects of the above structure and can we have pointers which point to the node objects itself .I am new to programming in C++ so please guide me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is perfectly allowed. You create an object with:

```
node<int> int_node;
```

And you can dynamically allocation one with:

```
node<int>* p_int_node = new node<int>();
```

Comment: But, please, _do not_. We do not use raw pointers in C++ any more.

Answer (score 0):

In C++, a `struct` is the same as a `class`, except that everything defaults to `public` instead of `private`.

Therefore you *can* have a struct template, and everything you want to do with it works just the same as with a class template. For example:

```
node<int> n1; // a `int` node
node<int> *n2 = new node<int>(); // pointer to dynamically allocated instance
```

Comment: <pedantic>Structs aren't "the same as" a class; they _are_ classes — or, more accurately, _user-defined types_.. They are one-and-the-same entity. The access difference is essentially syntactical, and comes from whether you use _struct-key_ `struct` or _class-key_ `class` to define your user-defined type.</pedantic>